# referring to elements with ggplot using melted dataframes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

Suppose I melt the `iris` dataframe as follows for plotting with ggplot2:

```
meltediris <- melt(iris)
```

I can now plot the `Petal.Width` values by selecting them out from the `variable` column:

```
ggplot(meltediris) + geom_density(aes(x=meltediris[meltediris$variable == 
                                                          "Petal.Width",]$value))
```

I wanted to then plot the `Petal.Width` values by `Species`, so I did:

```
ggplot(meltediris) + geom_density(aes(x=meltediris[meltediris$variable ==
                                          "Petal.Width",]$value, colour=Species))
```

It appears to work but I am surprised that it does! The selected subset of the dataframe `meltediris[meltediris$variable == "Petal.Width",]$value` does not have the same index as the entire melted dataframe (it's only a subset), so how does ggplot know to pick the right `Species` values? It seems like it should have required me to do instead:

```
ggplot(meltediris) + geom_density(aes(x=meltediris[meltediris$variable == 
                                  "Petal.Width",]$value, 
                     colour=meltediris[meltediris$variable == "Petal.Width",]$Species))
```

which picks the `Species` values of the selected subset of the melted dataframe. To give another example, if I do:

```
ggplot(meltediris) + geom_density(aes(x=meltediris[meltediris[meltediris$variable == "Petal.Width",]$Species == "virginica",]$value, colour=Species))
```

it seems like ggplot should only know about one species, since I selected out the non-virginicas.  When I do this, it plots correctly only one species, but still in the legend displays the other two `Species` values. How does it know to do this? I was sure that when I pass it `x=` that it cannot read the remaining dataframe values. 
Can someone explain how ggplot picks these variables from melted dataframes? thanks.

Comment: Your code without subsetting also Species gives an error of not the same length - so it is not working at least for me - ggplot2 version 0.9.3., x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64

Comment: It works here - which line in particular did you have trouble executing?

Comment: I got error in both examples where you didn't subset also Species (just uses colour=Species).

Comment: I am using Rstudio but not sure that could explain the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it is said in the comment , When I try this :

```
ggplot(meltediris) + geom_density(
                         aes(x=meltediris[meltediris$variable ==
                                              "Petal.Width",]$value, colour=Species))
```

I get this error:

```
Error:  Aesthetics must either be length one, 
        or the same length as the dataProblems:
                    meltediris[meltediris$variable == "Petal.Width", ]$value
```

As the error suggests you must give *aes* with same length. Here no need to give the `data` argument since you give all values in the aes(your *aes* are vectors)

For example,

```
 X <-   meltediris[meltediris$variable =="Petal.Width",]$value
 Col <- meltediris[meltediris$variable == "Petal.Width",]$Species
ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x=X,colour=Col))
```

But I it is better to subset all the data.frame meltediris in this case.

```
ggplot(meltediris) + geom_density(aes(x=variable,colour=Species),
               subset=.(variable=="Petal.Width"))
```